# Git: list all commits on all remote branches?

Tags: git

I would like to list all commits on all remote branches in my repository.

I just want the SHA1 for each commit.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
git rev-list --remotes
```

The [documentation for the `--remotes` option](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html#_options) says:

> --remotes[=<pattern>]
>
> Pretend as if all the refs in refs/remotes are listed on the command line as <commit>. If <pattern> is given, limit remote-tracking branches to ones matching given shell glob. If pattern lacks ?, , or [, / at the end is implied.

As a point of pedantry, these are "remote-tracking branches" rather than "remote branches" - the latter is a somewhat ambiguous term in git, since you might be referring to a branch in remote repository or a remote-tracking branch (which is like a cache of the state of the branch in the remote repository).

Comment: `git rev-list --all --remotes --pretty`

Answer (score 65):

Try this:

```
git log --branches="*"
```

Comment: This filters much better for my needs because I can exclude other authors and merges.

Comment: For the record @DavidMann - you can add options for authors and merges with rev-list as well: git rev-list --remotes --author="th3morg*" --date=iso --pretty --branches="*" --no-merges

Comment: May I know using the flag `--all` in this commands means same as `--branches=*`?

Comment: zsh: no matches found: --branches=*

Comment: @neoexpert add quotes around the * . I also updated the answer, works that way in both bash and zsh.

Answer (score 19):

Simple:

```
git rev-list --all --remotes
```

I hope that helps

Of course, drop the --all if you *just* want to list revisions in remotes (which 90% of the time will overlap those in your local branches)

Comment: `--all` will also include local branches, though.

Comment: true. A matter of interpretation really.

Answer (score 2):

If you want refrences with it use this--

```
git show-ref
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who wants to copy/paste it from a GUI to, say Excel.

[Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) has a **History** function where you can see every commit from all branches, with description, time and author